# Do curves in GIMP have "targeted adjustments" like in Photoshop?

Tags: gimp, curves

Is there a targeted adjustment feature in the curves settings of GIMP. To set colour curves. Like in Photoshop?

[image: Photoshop curves]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question about using an image editing tool without a clear application to photography. Could you please edit your question to explain the _photography_ issue you're trying to solve? Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) Rather than ask us how to do what you think you need to do to fix your problem… why not ask us about your problem?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Is there any SE site where this woud be on-topic?

Comment: Curves don't work in 'user-selected' colours, hence my XY comment. You have decided this is how to fix your issue. What you need to do is ask about your actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves tool in GIMP does **not** have any adjustment droppers (see the screenshot). However, **the levels tool does**.

- You can make rough adjustments with the levels tool and switch over to the curves tool by clicking the button labeled "Edit these Settings as Curves".
- If you click on the image, a vertical line will appear in the curves dialog to show the corresponding portion of the curve.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, because the Curves dialog acts along a single dimension. What you require would have to work along 3 dimensions (ie, pick a point in a volume).

If you want to match colors, see [here](https://patdavid.net/2012/06/getting-around-in-gimp-color-curves.html) and [here](https://patdavid.net/2012/07/getting-around-in-gimp-more-color.html).

Comment: Curves tool has two dimensions... there's the input axis and the output axis.

Comment: Yes, and this means it acts on one dimension. `output=function(input)`.

Comment: I'm no mathematician, but doesn't that actually make it a 2-dimensional array, by the time you have all possible values for input & output?

Comment: @Tetsujin No. An actual setting is a list of 256 output values, indexed by the output values, so it has only one dimension.

Comment: Since there are separate curves for Luminance and color channels, the input can be considered four dimensional.